# App freezes after popping a view

Tags: swift, apple-tv

I have the main window where I just load a collection view like this

```
let urlString = "http://example.url"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            let jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
            let arrayImagenes1 = jsonResult["franjas"]! as! NSMutableArray
            arrayImagenes1.removeObject(at: 0)
            arrayImagenes1.removeObject(at: 0)
            self.arrayImagenes = arrayImagenes1 as NSArray
            print (self.arrayImagenes)
                self.franjasCollection.reloadData()
        }
    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
```

And in that view I call a login window where I just login to the app like this

```
let urlString = "http://example.login"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: {
        data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            let jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
            if jsonResult["username"] != nil {
                let usuario = jsonResult["username"]! as? NSString
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                    let username = Usuario(context: context) // Link Task & Context
                    username.username = usuario! as String
                    }
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
                Variables.loginbool = true
                let _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)               
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Inti", message: (jsonResult["error"]! as! NSString) as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
```

So, after the user succesfully login in the app, I use this line

```
let _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

But when it comes back to the Main View the collection view is frozen and I can not navigate in it, I can only click the login button

PD: it is an apple tv app

Comment: popViewController should happen on mainthread... and presenting alert too

Comment: thanks @TomaszCzyżak this solved my issue